# Arranging hourly data for several years

Tags: time-series

I have hourly data for a variable for several years. I want to analyse each month separately. How do I arrange the data for the same month of different years?

For example, suppose I have Jan 1997, Jan 1998m and Jan 1999. Do I have to find a mean for say 18 Jan 1997, 18 Jan 1998 and 18 Jan1999.

**Update**

```
Hours Jan 96 Jan97 Jan98 Jan99

01:00 3 2 4 7 02:00 5 2 6 5 . . . . . . . . . . . 23:00 NA 5 7 3 00:00 01:00 . . .
```

The dots each represent a value and the data is for all days of the month. NA means that the value is missing.

Comment: You need to state what software package you are using.

Answer (score 8):

Could you give an example of what your dataset looks like?  You're probably looking for the [reshape command](http://gbi.agrsci.dk/~shd/misc/Rdocs/reshape.pdf).

Lets say you have a dataframe with 2 columns, Date and X, where X is the time series you want to analyze.  This dataset is in "long" form, with one observation per row.  To convert it to "wide" form, where each month is a separate column, do something like this:

```
Date<-c('2009-01-01','2009-02-01','2010-01-01','2010-02-01')
X<-c(1,2,3,4)
Year<-as.numeric(format(as.POSIXct(Date), "%Y"))
Month<-as.numeric(format(as.POSIXct(Date), "%m"))

df<-as.data.frame(cbind(Year,Month,X))
df
df<-reshape(df,v.names='X',idvar="Year",timevar='Month',direction='wide')
df

mean(df$X.1)  #January mean
mean(df$X.2)  #Feb mean
```